# Why does the following getString() function written by me in C won't work?

Tags: c, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* getString()
{
    char buffer;
    int size = 0;
    int capacity = 1;

    char* inputString = (char*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
    char* newString;

    while(1)
    {
        buffer = getchar();
        if(buffer == '\n')
            break;
        if((capacity-1) <= size)
        {
            capacity *= 2;
            newString = (char*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
                newString[i] = inputString[i];
            inputString = newString;
            free(newString);
        }
        inputString[size] = buffer;
        size++;
    }
    inputString[size] = '\0';
    return inputString;
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    str = getString();
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

I wrote this C program to get a String as a user input in C and store it in a dynamically resizable array. However, every time I run this program, it crashes.
I went through similar implementations of this program, but couldn't exactly figure out whats wrong with my code

Comment: Did you use a debugger? That is the way to debug such issues (and post on Stackoverflow as a last resort).

Comment: `*buffer = getchar();` Review your code to answer: Where does `buffer` point to? Try `char buffer = getchar();`

Comment: @kalyum tried that, still no use

Comment: @kalyum debugger says segmentation fault

Comment: Nonsense. It certainly is of use because `*buffer` is derefencing an uninitialised pointer. You have other issues and changing just that one line is not sufficient. For example, did you also change the other `*buffer`? I'm guessing you didn't. Please edit your quesiton to show any updated code as an addition to your question.

Comment: Then you are asking the wrong question from the debugger. Of course it tells you there is a segmentation fault. You are supposed to use it to step through your program before that occurs and examine each line of code to see whether the values are expected after each line. So you don't just need to use the debugger you need to use it *effectively*.

Comment: `buffer` is an uninitialised pointer.  `*buffer = getchar()` therefore gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just review your code line by line.`inputString = newString; free(newString);`. What do you think happens to the `inputString` buffer after the `free` considering it is exactly the same buffer as `newString`?

Comment: `inputString = newString;            free(newString);` frees the current buffer and doesn't free the old one

Comment: One problem you've got is that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, so you are throwing away information and cannot reliably detect EOF.  You don't try to detect EOF, which sort of makes up for it, but it also leads to things going horribly wrong if EOF is encountered before you get a newline.  That will happen eventually.  You must think about EOF and handle it.  And the type of `buffer` should be `int`, and the name is a misnomer — a buffer is normally an array, not a single element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
        capacity *= 2;
        newString = (char*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            newString[i] = inputString[i];
        inputString = newString;
        free(newString);
```

What this is trying to do is...

1. Allocate a bigger string.
2. Copy the old string to the new one.
3. Use the new string.
4. Free the old string.

But it isn't. The problem is `inputString = newString` means `inputString` points at `newString`'s memory. When you then `free(newString)` that's also `inputString`'s memory.

What you want instead is to `free(inputString)`, the old memory, before copying `newString`'s pointer.

```
        capacity *= 2;
        newString = (char*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            newString[i] = inputString[i];
        free(inputString);
        inputString = newString;
```

---

Some notes.

You should start with a capacity of at least 2, because a string with a capacity of 1 can only hold a null byte.

The string copy can be done better with [`strncpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm).

```
        capacity *= 2;
        newString = (char*)malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
        strncpy( newString, inputString, size );
        free(inputString);
        inputString = newString;
```

Even though `newString` is big enough to hold the contents of `inputString`, we still need to use `strncpy` with a limit because `inputString` is not null terminated. Otherwise it would read garbage off the end of the string.

`strncpy` isn't particularly safe, it doesn't null terminate when it stops copying, but for this particular instance where you'll null terminate at the end it's fine.

Next, this is all unnecessary. It can be done with [`realloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm). This grows, shrinks, or reallocates memory, copying if necessary.

```
        capacity *= 2;
        inputString = realloc(inputString, capacity * sizeof(char));
        if( inputString == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Reallocation failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: The `inputString` is not null-terminated until the loop exits; the use of `strcpy()` is unreliable.  Using `memmove()` or `memcpy()` would be more appropriate. And the `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` meme is a memory-leak in waiting — you should have `newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr != 0) oldptr = newptr; else { …handle error… }` for safety.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I knew I missed something. Is there any advantage to `memcpy` vs `strncpy` here? You'll forgive me if I skimp a bit on the `realloc` error handling, that's its own subject.

Comment: It'll be marginal, but yes; `strncpy()` has to both count and check for null bytes (which it won't find), whereas `memcpy()` only has to count.